# CX_Freeze Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

Tags: python, ubuntu, cx-freeze

I am trying to use CX_Freeze to distribute python code for multiple platforms. In windows all went well but I am stuck trying to use CX_Freeze 5 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with python 3.4. I am able to run CX_Freeze without error, however when I run the resulting binary I get

```
/Desktop/cx/cx_Freeze/samples/simple/build/exe.linux-i686-3.4$ ./hello
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This happens even with the "simple" example included with CX_Freeze (as well as my program) so I believe the problem has to do with my install.

I was able to get CX_Freeze to install using this https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304 workaround.

I have read that CX_Freeze can have trouble finding modules imported into python in strange ways, and that the solution is to add those files manually to the setup.py file and put the files into same folder, however there is no encodings.py file in \usr\lib\python3.4 however there is a \usr\lib\python3.4\encodings folder.

I'm sure the my problem is that I have no idea what I am doing, but I followed all of the installation directions as best I could and still ran into this problem. After two days of looking I haven't found a good answer yet so I'm going to ask here. If  answer is found, maybe it will help someone else as well. Thank you for any advice you can give.

Edit: Judging from the number of views this post has gotten it is not a very common problem, however I found a solution and I want to share it in the hopes that it will help someone. The solution was to use cx_Freeze 4.3.3 instead of 5. You can find version 4.3.3 here as a tar.gz file https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=cx_Freeze&version=4.3.3 . You then need to make the changes described in the first link in this post make it build right. This solved the issue for me on Linux, but not on OSX. Good luck!

Comment: I downloaded cx_Freeze from https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze ,is it  CX_Freeze 5?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more, but I would guess that you downloaded CX_Freeze 5 because that link is to the site which hosts the most recent version of CX_Freeze. There are however ways to download an older version from that site also.

Comment: Looks like the same issue as #28258991. cx_Freeze has issues on Debian/Ubuntu. If you need to use v5, get it from here: https://github.com/peacegiverman/cx_Freeze-deb-wheels.